# CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess not close randomly

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, cefsharp

all

Operating environment: win7 x64 , cef x64

I had a browser use CefSharp.winforms 65. In browser i use the code to close

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           Cef.Shutdown();

        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {

            Console.WriteLine( ee.ToString());

        }


    }
```

Then in other exe I use Process to call browser.

```
            process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
```

Use the code to close browser.

```
process.Kill();
```

About 100 times call browser ,close browser. Afterwards about **5** CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess **did not close**. and the cpu is 100%.

Comment: `Process.Kill` is going to give you an unclean shutdown, you need to ask your process to `Close` instead. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thranks for reply. It's a good idea.